# assiging makes pointer integer witout cast

Tags: mysql, c

hello all i have write a c program which connects to a mysql server and executes a sql query from a text file which has only one query.

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
char *server = "127.0.0.1";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "PASSWORD"; /* set me first */
char *database = "har";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

char ch, file_name[25];
char *ch1;
FILE *fp;

printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see ");
gets(file_name);

fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

if( fp == NULL )
{
perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
exit(0);
}

while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
printf("%c",ch);


ch1=ch;


/* Connect to database */
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
NULL , NULL, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
exit(0);
}


printf("%c",ch);


/* send SQL query */
if (mysql_query(conn, ch1)) {
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
exit(0);
}
res = mysql_use_result(conn);
/* output table name */
printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
printf("%s \n", row[0]);
/* close connection */
mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(conn);
fclose(fp);
}
```

i am unable to understand where i have gone wrong....
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

This is the line causing problem:
ch1=ch;

ch1 is a pointer to a character, whereas ch is a character.

Do you intend to store the bytes read from fp in a char array pointed by ch1? What you are doing is, every time in the while loop you are reading a character using fgetc storing it in ch and printing it.

Then, when while loop gets over, you are assigning a char to a char pointer. I am not sure what you are trying to do with this. But this definitely causes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're going wrong in a lot of ways:

1. You don't declare the return type or arguments for `main`.
2. You're using `gets`. Never ever use [`gets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html), don't even think about. Use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) instead.
3. [`fgetc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) returns an `int`, not a `char` so your `ch` should be an `int`. You won't be able to recognize EOF until you fix this.
4. You're declaring `char ch` and `char *ch1` but assigning `ch` to `ch1`. That's where the error in your title is coming from.
5. Your code appears to be trying feed your SQL to MySQL one byte at a time and that's not going to do anything useful. I think you're meaning to use `fgets` to read the SQL file one line a time so that you can feed each line to MySQL as a single SQL statement.

You should spend some time reading about your compiler's warning switches